# export cmyk vector to rgb jpeg or cmyk tif for usage in Indesign

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

We make vector patterns in Illustrator CMYK, which from there are used for prepress. But I need to export these patterns as a picture to be used in Indesign. Until now I exported these as tiffs CMYK, but now I am doubting what is the best way to go? 
Export as jpegs in RGB, or CMYK? Or stick to the tiffs in cmyk?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. How are the InDesign files being printed or distributed?  Are they being printed professionally using an offset press, where separations will be required, or are they being distributed electronically for viewing on a computer, or home/office printing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can link vector AI files in InDesign without the need to convert these to JPG or TIF. More so since you appear to print these patterns, in which case a vector file is generally sharper at a much lower file size (generally).

If you need to stick to raster files, then it depends on the type of print you are doing. Generally again, either JPG or TIF in either RGB or CMYK should work, assuming you will do a final export from InDesign which will convert everything to CMYK when exporting, which can be achieved using the built-in PDF/X1A export preset.

If image compression is a concern and you need to preserve as much detail as possible in your patterns, probably better avoid JPG, but that needs to be tested first.

Comment: Yes, this used to be the case before. But that made the catalogue very heavy to generate. The patterns are sometimes quite heavy. Also for afterwards exporting to a small sized pdf this gave problems. Basically, the designs are sold and need to be put in a catalogue. But the original files are all made in Illustrator cmyk environment.

Comment: Thank you Lucian, that really did answer my question, now I can start exporting :-)

Answer (score 0):

I often save AI artwork as a raster image in order to reduce the final size of a printed piece.

For me, the best option is to **open the AI file in Photoshop, and save as a CMYK PSD** with the smart object embedded. It *drastically* cuts down redraw times (especially in PDFs from Indesign). And it's a simple matter to replace the smart object contents later if there was a change to the original AI artwork.

Note that .PSD **is** a compressed format as well.

For print projects I, personally, don't do *any* RGB in InDesign whatsoever or RGB formats such as jpg, png, gif.